# Two components trigger the same event

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have simple component with radio buttons:

Html:

```
<div class="rate">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" (change)="onRateChange($event.target.value)"/>
  <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
...
</div>
```

Ts:

```
@Output() rateSelected = new EventEmitter<number>();

public onRateChange(value: number) {
    this.rateSelected.emit(value);
  }
```

And When I use it like:

Html:

```
<form>
  <h1>Rate one:</h1>
  <app-stars (rateSelected)="onRateOneSelected($event)"></app-stars>

  <h1>Rate two:</h1>
  <app-stars (rateSelected)="onRateTwoSelected($event)"></app-stars>
</form>
```

Ts:

```
  onRateOneSelected(rate: number) {
    alert('app ' + rate); // this one is always triggered
  }

  onRateTwoSelected(rate: number) {
    alert('comfort ' + rate);
  }
```

Regardless of whether I use the first or second rating always `onRateOneSelected` event is triggered. What is wrong? How can I fix that?

Comment: This looks fine..? What does the consuming component looks like?

Comment: I've added ts code to question.

Comment: The names in the ts don't match the html

Comment: It's not the case, I've changed names for question purposes. Here's github page: https://github.com/Makulak/HCC